# AngularJS - Separate controller and DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I was reading the angular documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

and it has a bit that says:

> Do not use controllers to:
>
> Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic.
>   Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects
>   its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives
>   to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

So I have the following code that works well.

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
    // Get and reset the captcha, then check it was valid.
    response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    $scope.recaptchaValid = false;
    grecaptcha.reset();

    if (response.length == 0) {
        alert("Not sure how you got here, but you shouldn't have. Go away!");
        return;
    }

    // Update the user we are attempting to send the message.
    $(".contact-message").text("Sending message...").removeClass("hidden alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
    $(".contact-container").addClass("hidden");

    // Add the recaptcha data to the form so we can send it to the server easier
    $scope.formData.captcha = response;

    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/api/sendEmail.php',
        data : $.param($scope.formData), // pass in data as strings
        headers : {
            // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            // If the server said there was an error, re-enable the form and display the error
            console.error(data);
            $(".contact-container").removeClass("hidden");
            $(".contact-message").text(data.message).removeClass("hidden alert-success").addClass("alert-danger");
        } else {
            // If the server said all was good, display the message from the server
            $(".contact-message").text(data.message).removeClass("hidden alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
        }
    });
};
```

From an interpretive zen like purist, I'm seeing that the handling of doing the backend API call should probably be off in a service somewhere (although not sure how to do this), but I'm not really sure how I interact with the data in $scope 'correctly', and is the DOM manipulation ok to do in there? I have reduced the DOM manipulation to manage classes for the most part but the sending setup update, I think should be a div on it's own driven off some scope data and using ng-hide. I see this could probably really useful if you're language selecting, but will make the HTML page large and cumbersome when maintaining.

Any help appreciated.

### EDIT

Based on where I was going and the note from @C14L, I updated the code the Angular code to this:

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
    // Get and reset the captcha, then check it was valid.
    response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    $scope.recaptchaValid = false;
    grecaptcha.reset();

    if (response.length == 0) {
        alert("Not sure how you got here, but you shouldn't have. Go away!");
        return;
    }

    // Update the user we are attempting to send the message.
    $scope.sendingMessage = true;

    // Add the recaptcha data to the form so we can send it to the server easier
    $scope.formData.captcha = response;

    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/api/sendEmail.php',
        data : $.param($scope.formData), // pass in data as strings
        headers : {
            // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.serverMessage = data.message;
        $scope.sendingStatus = data.success;
        $scope.sendingMessage = false; // no longer sending
    });
};
```

I have to admit this does work a load better. The HTML is a bit knarlier though:

```
    <div class='sending-indicator alert alert-info' data-ng-hide="!sendingMessage">
        <p>Sending message...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="alert contact-message" 
            data-ng-class="sendingStatus?'alert-success':'alert-danger'" 
            data-ng-hide="serverMessage.length == 0">{{serverMessage}}</div>
    <div  class="contact-container" 
            data-ng-hide="sendingMessage || (sendingStatus && serverMessage.length > 0)">

...
```

Comment: DOM manipulation should be done inside directives. Also avoid calling JQuery, as you can use almost all with angular functions (Angular uses a lite version of JQuery, JQlite).

Comment: Directives, use them. Instead of calling `addClass` you can use `ng-class` directive in your view

Comment: Yeah, I can see that for the process of sending, but what about the process management and server feedback? It seems like a really old concept to have a list of error messages the server and viewer share but the transport knows nothing of. If I invent a new check or error on the sever I need to update at least 2 places... this seems to be the "unhandled exception" curse of bad java and C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking these lines as an example

```
// Update the user we are attempting to send the message.
$(".contact-message").text("Sending message...").removeClass("hidden alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
$(".contact-container").addClass("hidden");
```

You could write them like this. In the template

```
<div class="contact-message" ng-if="sendingMessage">Sending message</div>
<div class="contact-container" ng-if="!sendingMessage">Not sending</div>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.sendingMessage = true;  // now it shows "sending"
$scope.sendingMessage = false;  // now "not sending"
```

Comment: That's where I thought I was going with that one, but I think I'm more concerned about the $http and managing the various steps and errors. That's a process based thingy... I think I'm still oldschool... should I use $scope variables there as well?

Comment: Exactly. In your $http resolve, assign `data.message` to a variable on the $scope, e.g. `$scope.dataMessage = data.message;` and then display it in the template with `{{ dataMessage }}`.